# Two values equal the same add class Red

Tags: jquery

I have two links using the value="valuehere" attribute and I'm trying to get jQuery to have it so when I click the **The DEF** link it selects out of the top links the link that has the same value as *THE DEF* link. I would love it also if I could shorten the code also. At the moment it applies the class of Red to all the div's and I only want it to the valid one.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/n7VMY/20/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test" value="00">abc</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test2" value="01">def</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test3 "value="02">ghi</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 4</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test4" value="03">zyx</a></span></li>
</ul>
<div class="test">
 random text
</div>
<div id="thisdiv">
    <a href="#" value="01" class='mcdiv'>The DEF</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click','.mcdiv',function(){

$(".num a").each(function(i,v){
   var $info = $(this);

   $(".mcdiv").each(function(i,v){
       var $thisdivlink = $(this);

      if($info.val()==$thisdivlink.val()){
          $info.addClass( 'red' );
       }

   });
});

});
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled {
    color:#ccc;
}
.num { padding: 10px 10px; line-height: 30px; }
.red { color: red !important;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
}

.test {
padding: 30px 30px;
font-size: 28px;
color: purple;
}
#thisdiv a {
 display: block;
 background: purple;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 28px;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

I'm slowly learning jQuery and finding this community amazing as I go with things I really struggle with, so thanks a lot!

Comment: check my answer and snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, use this**
You need use `.attr('value')` not `.val()` function

Try with this.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mcdiv', function() {
  var foo = $(this).attr('value')
  $('a[value="'+ foo +'"]').toggleClass('red')
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #ccc;
}
.num {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.red {
  color: red !important;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.test {
  padding: 30px 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: purple;
}
#thisdiv a {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test" value="00">abc</a></span>
  </li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test2" value="01">def</a></span>
  </li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test3 "value="02">ghi</a></span>
  </li>
  <li><span>Item 4</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test4" value="03">zyx</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="test">
  random text
</div>
<div id="thisdiv">
  <a href="#" value="01" class='mcdiv'>The DEF</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I mean :) that makes sense I can follow that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` tag does not have any attribute called **value** so either use data-* attribute or define new attribute

```js
$(document).on('click','.mcdiv',function(){

$(".num a").each(function(i,v){
   var $info = $(this);

   $(".mcdiv").each(function(i,v){
       var $thisdivlink = $(this);
     
       if($info.data('val')==$thisdivlink.data('val')){
          $info.addClass( 'red' );
       }
       
   });
});

});
```

```css
.disabled {
    color:#ccc;
}
.num { padding: 10px 10px; line-height: 30px; }
.red { color: red !important;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
}

.test {
padding: 30px 30px;
font-size: 28px;
color: purple;
}
#thisdiv a {
 display: block;
 background: purple;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 28px;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test" data-val="00">abc</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test2" data-val="01">def</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test3 " data-val="02">ghi</a></span></li>
    <li><span>Item 4</span>: <span class="num"><a href="#test4" data-val="03">zyx</a></span></li>
</ul>
<div class="test">
random text
</div>
<div id="thisdiv">
    <a href="#" data-val="01" class='mcdiv'>The DEF</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, other solutions work but this is good to know for coding purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like that: http://jsfiddle.net/n7VMY/21/
Clicking on .mcdiv value=01 -> add 'red' class on .num a value=01 and remove red class from the other.

```
$(document).on('click','.mcdiv',function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  $('.num a').removeClass('red');
  $('.num a[value="'+value+'"]').addClass('red');
})
```

Comment: Thanks @progysm works exactly how I need it to work as well. Only gave Rui the solution tick cause he was first, but yours is just as good :)

Comment: his/her answer showed after me, and rewrite it a lot of time to use my solution with the attribute selector, but using toggleClass.